# Is there a pandas function to add in value of a column based on the other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column to a pandas dataframe based on the value from another dataframe. Here is table 1 and table 2. I would like to update the duration for table 1 based on the value from table 2. Eg, row 1 in Table 1 is Potato, so the duration should be updated to 30 based on value from table 2.

Table 1

| Crops | Entry Time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Potato | 2022-03-01 | 0 |
| Cabbage | 2022-03-02 | 0 |
| Tomato | 2022-03-03 | 0 |
| Potato | 2022-03-0 | 0 |

Table 2

| Crops | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Potato | 30 |
| Cabbage | 20 |
| Tomato | 25 |

Thanks.

Comment: The merge method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 2):

Just use merge method:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Crops', how='left')
```

Before doing that I suggest to drop the duration column in the first dataframe (df1).

The parameter 'on' defines on which column you want to merge (also called 'key') and how='left' it returns a dataframe with the length of the first dataframe. Imposing 'left' avoids that records with 'vegetables'in df1 that are not present in df2 will be deleted.

Google 'difference between inner, left, right and outer join'.